# A single line separator after paragraph in phpword?

Tags: php

I Want to separate my paragraph which comes dynamically from a website with a line like this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7sl5.png) is there any way to do this?

here is my code

```
         $j++;
     }

     $k = $j - 1;
     $k++;

     $i = $k - 1;
     $i++;

     $summary = str_replace("<br>", "$section->addText", $summary);
     $summary = str_replace("<br />", "$section->addText", $summary);
     $summary = str_replace("<p>", "$section->addText", $summary);
     $summary = str_replace("</p>", " ", $summary);

     $section-> addText(cleanstring($summary), $styleFont, $fontStyleIndexParaSummary);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `explode` function of php and use `<hr>` tag for print the line

for example, consider `$string` is your response then and you want to add a line after every paragraph (if you want to add line after new line then change delimiter `</p>` to `</br>`)

```
$string ="<p>para1</p><p>para2</p><p>para3</p>";
$str_arr = explode ("</p>", $string); 
foreach ($str_arr as $value) {
    echo "$value</p><hr>";

}
```

OUTPUT:

para1

---

para2

---

para3

---

---

Comment: brother i need single line after a paragraph please see image  in my question.

Comment: your answer is correct brother but it doesn't fit with my code why?